# How to get year and month from firebase?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I have this field in firebase "cloud firestore"
[firebase date field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUOfh.png)

and in cloud functions I want to extract (get only the year from this date, the year alone and month alone)

```
  const year = BookedSessionChanges.bookedAt.toDate();
    console.log("yearr ", year);
    const month = BookedSessionChanges.bookedAt.toDate();
    console.log("month ", month);
```

here's the code in cloud function, where i used toDate() to convert the date shown in above image to look like 2020-10-06T08:38:14.066Z time beside it.

So how can I get only the year and then the month from this date?
**Ps.** I tried getYear() and toDate("Y") ... but none of these works.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method converts Firestore Timestamp object to a Javascript Date object.
After conversion you can use `getYear()` method to extract the year.

```
const year = BookedSessionChanges.bookedAt.toDate().getYear();
```

Comment: Now I checked it and found that I should use getFullYear() instead of getYear() since the year is above 2000 and it worked. Thanks, I'll add my answer below.